# What house was Hagrid in before being expelled?

Tags: harry-potter, hagrid

Hagrid, as shown in Chamber of Secrets, was once a student at Hogwarts, but was expelled from the school when Tom Marvolo Riddle framed him for keeping dangerous pets in the school.

Since Hagrid was going to Hogwarts, what house was Hagrid a member of before his expulsion?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

According to this [Barnes & Noble webchat](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2000/1000-livechat-barnesnoble.html) on October 20, 2000, Hagrid was sorted into  Gryffindor (of course)

> **Yahooligan_seachellie4 asks:** *What house was Hagrid in?*
>
> **jkrowling_bn:** *Hagrid was in Gryffindor, naturally!*

Comment: Of course.  Always Gryffindor.

Comment: Nothin' good came from those other houses, anyway.

Comment: "Nothin' good came from those other houses, anyway" really because last time I checked Tonks was a Hufflepuff, Luna was a Ravenclaw, and Headmaster Phineas Nigellus Black was a Slytherin. Plus, almost all of the main characters' development were because of characters from Slytherin.

Comment: @Dragona13: I'm pretty sure that statement was a sarcastic riff on the fact that all three main characters are in Gryffindor, which is also associated with all the clichéd "heroic" attributes and sure makes it seem at first glance like it's the only house that's worth anything.

Comment: Hagrid's main personality trait is insane courage in the face of dangerous creatures, which makes him a natural for Gryffindor.

Comment: So the scene in CoS(the movie) where Tom Riddle enters Hagrid's room and finds the Acromantula is wrong, isn't it? Otherwise Tom, being a Slytherin, wouldn't have been able to get past the Fat Lady portrait.

Comment: @A.Darwin I don't remember the details, but IIRC Hagrid kept Aragog in a closet near the dungeons or something along those lines, not his room.

Comment: @Cubic you're right! I didn't remember.

Comment: I'm wondering why a direct answer from JKR was at all necessary.  Hagrid very painfully obviously is not a Ravenclaw, and the way he speaks about Hufflepuff and Slytherin strongly indicate that he wasn't in either of those houses either.

Answer (score 5):

Pottermore confirms Hagrid was in Gryffindor in addition to the interview quote given above.

[Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/rubeus-hagrid)

[image]

Comment: Although that only means that someone on the Pottermore team either saw the interview or just copied the information from the wiki.